# Plotlyjs curved lines for square shapes

Tags: javascript, plotly

Hey I am using plotlyjs inorder to draw an area chart of curved squares. The final result which I want to reach out it is like this:
[image]

I am trying to reach the above result, using plotlyjs library. I have created 3 squares each square with differen color: green,yellow and red.
Each square is a zone and if a point is on the green zone, this means that their health is OK, if it is on the yellow zone then its health is Warning, and if it is on the red zone then its health is Danger and so on...

Now I am trying make the square to have a curved lines so that it will appear as an arc like in the original picture.

I am looking for a solution to my problem, I thought but using 'path' instead of 'square' shape but then how can I draw the arc accordingly ?

I would be glad if an expert of plotlyjs can help my case,
thanks in advance.

This is what I have achieved so far using an example:

```js
var d3 = Plotly.d3

function normal_array( mean, stddev, size ){
    var arr = new Array(size), i;
    // from http://bl.ocks.org/nrabinowitz/2034281
    var generator = (function() {
        return d3.random.normal(mean, stddev);
    }());   
    
    for( i=0; i< arr.length; i++ ){
        arr[i] = generator();
    }
    return arr;
}

var x0 = normal_array(1, 0, 300);
var y0 = normal_array(1, 0, 300);

var x1 = normal_array(1, 0, 200);
var y1 = normal_array(1, 0, 200)

var x2 = normal_array(1, 0, 200);
var y2 = normal_array(1, 0, 200);


var data = [
    {    
        x: x0,
        y: y0,
        mode: 'markers'
    }, {
        x: x1,
        y: y1,
        mode: 'markers'                
    }, {
        x: x2,
        y: y2,
        mode: 'markers'          
    }, {
        x: x1,
        y: y0,
        mode: 'markers'          
    }             
];

var layout = {
    shapes: [
        {
            type: 'square',
            xref: 'x',
            yref: 'y',
            x0: 0,
            y0: 0,
            x1: 1,
            y1: 1,
            opacity: 0.7,
            fillcolor: 'green',
            line: {
                color: 'green'
            }
        },
        {
            type: 'square',
            xref: 'x',
            yref: 'y',
            x0: 0.5,
            y0: 0.5,
            x1: 1,
            y1: 1,
            opacity: 0.7,
            fillcolor: 'orange',
            line: {
                color: 'orange'
            }
        },
        {
            type: 'square',
            xref: 'x',
            yref: 'y',
            x0: 0.75,
            y0: 0.75,
            x1: 1,
            y1: 1,
            opacity: 0.7,
            fillcolor: 'red',
            line: {
                color: 'red'
            }
        }
        
    ],
    showlegend: false
}

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myDiv" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
```

**Edit:**
I have succeed to reach the following result, the svg is upside down I don't know how to rotate it in the right direction.
http://codepen.io/Barak/pen/apYvjW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following:

- Add 3 shapes, a green rectangle, a yellow and a red circle via `layout.shapes` (done via the `for` loop in the snippet)
- Make sure that the shapes are in the background via [`layer.shapes.layer: 'below'`](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/148)
- Hide the grid via `layout.x/yaxis.showgrid: false`
- Add the marker as a scatter plot

```js
var myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');
var types = ['square', 'circle', 'circle'];
var pos = [1, 0.7, 0.4];
var colors = ['green', 'yellow', 'red'];
var layout = {
    height: 400,
    width: 400,
    xaxis: {range: [0, 1], showgrid: false},
    yaxis: {range: [0, 1], showgrid: false}, 
    shapes: [],
};
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i +=1) {
    layout.shapes.push({
        type: types[i],
        x0: 1 - pos[i],
        y0: 1 - pos[i],
        x1: 1 + pos[i],
        y1: 1 + pos[i],
        fillcolor: colors[i],
        line: {
            color: colors[i]
        },
        layer: 'below'
    })
}

var data = [{
    type: 'scatter',
    x: [0.5], 
    y: [0.3],
    mode: "markers",
    marker: {
        color: 'black',
        size: 10},
    }]
Plotly.plot(myDiv, data, layout);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>
<div id='myDiv'></div>
```